# pymysql.err.Error: Already closed in flask on heroku

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, flask

Got an app on Heroku in a flask, I can follow routes that don't use the clearDB that has been set up, but whenever following routes which do, such as /articles below, I get this error;

[2019-07-27 03:39:24 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Error handling request /articles
...
pymysql.err.Error: Already closed

I know that this must have something to do with the close commands and connections, but I cannot figure it out since none of the examples I found seem to match what the tutorial I followed came up with (mainly because I had to use flaskext.mysql instead of something like sqlalchemy because windows dev is a real pain)

```python
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, session, logging, request
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from wtforms import Form, StringField, TextAreaField, PasswordField, validators
from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt
from functools import wraps

#instaniation
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key= 'secret123'

#config
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'b21efc8e2903de'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '190f67c9'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'heroku_0c6326c59d8b6e9'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor' #a cursor is a connection to let us run methods for queries. We set is as a dictionary

#init MySQL
mysql = MySQL(app, cursorclass=DictCursor)
mysql.init_app(app)

...
@app.route('/articles')
def articles():
    #create Cursor
    cur = mysql.get_db().cursor() #to execute commands
    #cur.execute("USE heroku_0c6326c59d8b6e9")

    #get articles
    result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM articles")
    #should retrieve all as a dictionary
    articles = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    if result > 0:
        return render_template('articles.html', articles=articles)
    else:
        msg= 'No Articles Found'
        return render_template('articles.html', msg=msg)
```

Comment: Did you try to remove "cur.close()" or move it to the end. Does it works locally ?

Comment: Everything worked locally originally. I had to make a few changes to enable it to work on Heroku. Removing cur.close() or moving it makes no difference at all, same error.

Comment: If those are your real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_. Instead of hard-coding this information you should get it from the environment. See [the Heroku ClearDB documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#using-the-cleardb-database-url) for more information.